# OpenJDK - com.sun:plugin

Tags: java, applet

We have some old applet which uses the `netscape.javascript` package (which I believe comes from `com.sun:plugin` package.

I just installed OpenJDK, and it doesn't have this package.

Is there an easy way to fix the project so it doesn't use this package anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add **plugins.jar** library to your project to be able to work with netscape.javascript classes. It is located in **\jre\lib** folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `plugins.jar` to the classpath. It's in `jre\lib` folder.